# Stanford CoreNLP how to skip failure when using a filelist?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using stanfordCoreNLP with filelist parameter. The program seems to fail at some files in the filelist.lst, and the cmd stopped and quit. How to skip the failure and continue to complete the analysis of the rest of the files?

java -mx3g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -props Props.properties

I have added continueOnAnnotateError Flag to the property file, but it still fails when hitting the bad files.

Props.properties file look like this:

```
annotators = tokenize, ssplit, pos, parse, sentiment
outputFormat = JSON 
outputDirectory = ./output_2020
timeout = 500000
output.includeText = False
parse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz
continueOnAnnotateError = True
filelist = ./flist253.lst
```

Here is the error I got with continueOnAnnotateError=True:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `-continueOnAnnotateError`

Comment: thanks, I put int the flag, but seems still failing, I updated my original post to include my property files, would you pls help? @StanfordNLPHelp

Comment: Could you please add the error produced on the files?

Comment: Please check I have just loaded the error msg to my original question, thank you for the help!

Comment: Please check I have just loaded the error msg to my original question, thank you for the help! @StanfordNLPHelp